# WINDOWID environment variable missing in gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.04

In Ubuntu 17.10 (under an Xorg session) I could get the window ID from the WINDOWID environment variable from
`gnome-terminal` by typing:

```
$ echo $WINDOWID
```

in the terminal window. In Ubuntu 18.04, this does not work. However, it seems to work fine with other terminal emulators I have tried, like `xterm` and `konsole`. 
So the issue seems to be specific to `gnome-terminal`.

How can I get the window id of the current `gnome-terminal` window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround. You can use

```
$ xdotool getactivewindow
```

This will give the window ID of the GNOME terminal window it is run from.